# SSRS - why is report dropdown data in preview different from data in report viewer?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, report

I'm already looking into this myself, but if you want some points for providing me and the community with any useful suggestions on things to check, or pointers on how the relevant parts of SSRS work that could help answer the question, then read on.....

- I'm using SSRS via SQL Server 2008 R2 Report Server
- When I preview my report (originally created by another developer) in VS2008 I see correct data in one of the dropdowns for my report:

[image]

- When I run the report via the report viewer on my machine at http://*localhost*/ReportServer_SQL2008, I see this - note the incorrect UID displaying in place of some recently added items in the dropdown (e.g. 'GRIT CARDIO'):

[image]

- I've re-built the report in VS2008, and I've manually re-uploaded the .rdl file to my report server using the Report Manager at http://*local-machine-name*/Reports_SQL2008/, but I still get the different data when using the IE report viewer.
- I've looked at where the data is coming from that's used for populating the program dropdown, using Query Analyser - when both viewing the report preview and viewing the report through the report viewer, the data is coming from the same database, using exactly the same stored procedure call
- The 'raw' data being pulled from SQL gets some processing before it's used in the relevant data field in the report - it gets processed by using a custom .NET assembly, to pull back a 'friendly' string based on the report user's locale. This uses .resx files held in the VS2012 project for the custom assembly, that transpose the data. The entries in the .resx all seem to be correct.
- I've manually deployed a debug version of the custom assembly that does this locale translation to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies (my own default location for custom assemblies)
- When I debug against this assembly in VS2012 by attaching VS2008 to the debug process and running the report preview in VS2008, the correct program name e.g. 'GRIT CARDIO' is returned

**So the question is 'why is this not being returned when I run the report in the IE report viewer'?**

To help clarify the problem, here is how the 'available values' are configured for my 'ProgramUid' parameter.  I'm confused as to why the parameter is 'ProgramUid' but the dropdown appears as 'Program' on the report:

[image]

And here is the 'Programs' dataset being used by the parameter:

[image]

Comment: Is the report server running under the same locale settings that the VS2008 computer has?

Comment: Good idea, however I don't think this would make a difference.  There's only one .resx file that contains the appropriate 'friendly' values for the programs, and when viewing the report via the report  viewer it seems the values here are being used for most of the programs.  I'm only getting the problem with the correct program name not being returned for newer programs that have been recently added.

Comment: Is the resx file redeployed to the server? Is there an old copy of the resx file the server is using, or is it cached somehow?

Comment: Hi Chris, that's what I'm trying to find out.  I've just asked a separate question about whether I need to deploy .resx files in some way (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078015/do-i-need-to-deploy-resx-files), as I don't really understand .resx deployment.  I've tried an IIS reset and this doesn't make a difference.

Comment: The invalid id (Lengthy text) indicates that the original value has been replaced with a system generated value as the original value or reference is not found.

Comment: Hi Maximus - yes, I think what's happening here is that because the appropriate entry isn't being found in the .resx files (because they seem to need to be separately deployed somehow), the report is just taking the 'value' for the dropdown item, which is a GUID for the program.

Comment: I"ve found this resource, that may help me figure out how to deploy the .resx files: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/294636/Localizing-SQL-Server-Reporting-Services-Reports

Answer (score 3):

Fixed.  Turns out that deploying the custom .dll to:

C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

allows the custom extension to be usable by the VS2008 report preview.  To allow SSRS to use the custom extension it needs to be deployed here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\ReportingServices\ReportServer\bin

and the .resx files do get compiled to the .dll, they don't need a separate deploy