# SSRS - different data depending on whether previewing report or using report viewer

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

**I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services.  I'm seeing different data in a dropdown that's on the report, depending on whether I'm running the report in 'preview' mode from VS2008, or whether I'm running it from the report viewer at http://*localhost*/ReportServer_SQL2008.  Any suggestions?**

- I'm using SSRS via SQL Server 2008 R2 Report Server
- When I preview my report (originally created by another developer) in VS2008 I see correct data in one of the dropdowns for my report:
- When I run the report via the report viewer on my machine at http://*localhost*/ReportServer_SQL2008, I see an incorrect GUID displaying in place of some recently added items in the dropdown
- I've re-built the report in VS2008, and I've manually re-uploaded the .rdl file to my report server using the Report Manager at http://*local-machine-name*/Reports_SQL2008/, but I still see the incorrect data when using the IE report viewer.
- I've looked at where the data is coming from that's used for populating the dropdown, using Query Analyser - when both viewing the report preview and viewing the report through the report viewer, the data is coming from the same database, using exactly the same stored procedure call
- The 'raw' data being pulled from SQL gets some processing before it's used in the relevant data field in the report - it gets processed by using a custom .NET assembly, to pull back a 'friendly' string based on the report user's locale. This uses .resx files held in the VS2012 project for the custom assembly , that transpose the data. The entries in the .resx all seem to be correct.
- I've manually deployed a debug version of the custom assembly that does this locale translation to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies (my own default location for custom assemblies)
- When I debug against this assembly in VS2012 by attaching VS2008 to the debug process and running the report preview in VS2008, the correct program name e.g. 'GRIT CARDIO' is returned

**So the question is 'why is this not being returned when I run the report in the IE report viewer'?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS - why is report dropdown data in preview different from data in report viewer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057861/ssrs-why-is-report-dropdown-data-in-preview-different-from-data-in-report-view)

Comment: Hi Chris - yes, I'm trying to ask the question in a clearer way.  Yours was the only response to the original question and I really need to solve this issue!  I still haven't been able to track down the cause after a few hours of effort and research.  If I just edited the original question, I wouldn't get any help as for this type of specific issue, I know from experience I'll only get any new responses on a new question.  I've upvoted your comment as it's provided the community with a useful link to the original, similar question.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work like a forum. If you can make the question clearer or have new information you should edit the original question rather than post a new one. This will bump it back up to the home page so more people see it as per [this entry in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers). You can also [put a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on it to get more attention.

Comment: Thanks Chris - wasn't aware of that.  I was keen though to keep the fuller info including the screenshots, but also supply this alternative, shorter, version that people may find less intimidating to review.  I can put the bounty on in a day, however I'm under pressure to get this issue fixed now!

Comment: Hey Chris, I've looked at the FAQ thanks.  What would you advise on the most effective way to update the original question?  Comments can easily be missed, I can't provide an 'answer' as such, so would I just edit the original post to provide the additional info?

Comment: Yes, just press the edit link at the bottom of the original question and edit it. StackOverflow works like a wiki, rather than a forum, so anyone can edit questions and answers to make them clearer. The idea is to have one canonical question with the best answer for every problem. Duplicate, off-topic, conversational, or poorly asked questions get closed fairly quickly.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I've done :)