# do I need to deploy .resx files for an SSRS custom extension?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, deployment, resx

When using .resx files within a VS2010 project using .NET 2.0, do the .resx files get compiled into the .dll for the project or do I need to deploy something else separately?

I'm trying to ensure that .resx files are included in the deploy for a custom dll being used by SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services)

(I've come across this resource that discusses compiling .resx files into common language runtime binary .resources files that can be embedded in a runtime binary executable or compiled into satellite assemblies, however I just want to deploy my solution so that it can utilize the .resx files in the project, I'm not trying to gain performance or modularity:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1.aspx)

Comment: What kind of project?

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that the answer is 'no', the .resx files get compiled into the .dll and don't need to be separately deployed.